# Incompatibilidad de Template Strings en Internet Exporer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, template-strings

Recien acabo de comprobar que los **template strings(``)** no son compatibles para IE(algo tarde pq esta en [MZD Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings))... cosa un un poco incomoda para mi pues habia escrito bastante codigo de esta forma por su comodidad lo uso casi siempre en vez de `'' y ""` o la `,`.. me gustaria saber porque esto y si existe alguna alternativa compatible para escribir codigo en **IE 9.x** en adelante y que esta a la vez esta sea compatible para las versiones de **Firefox a partir de la ver 52.x**, y **Chrome ver 45.x**

Tengo codigo con `` del tipo:

```
... = `<td>Inicio</td>
  <td>Totale</td>`;

... = `<option value="${[element]}">${element}</option>`; 

...`table${fecha}.xls`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los *template literals* o *template strings* es una sintaxis que se introdujo en el estándar ES2015. Por tanto [no puedes esperar que funcione](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals) en navegadores anteriores a finales de 2015.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. eliminar su uso de tu código
2. Usar un *traductor* que transforme el JS a código JS compatible con versiones de navegador antiguo.

Esto último es lo habitual hoy día, permitiendo trabajar siempre con las últimas herramientas durante el desarrollo y dejando la tarea de la compatibilidad a una herramienta como [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)